# Suspicious redirection to russian pages. Is government spying us?

Tags: networking, security, redirection, sniffing

Recently when I browse some multi-language websites the default language for them is Russian.

An example is [www.amd.com](http://www.amd.com) which redirects me to the russian page http://www.amd.com/ru/Pages/AMDHomePage.aspx.

I am sure I didn't change any settings related to language in my browser and windows.

I even tried on my friend's laptop. same result.

Based on the recent unrest and political issues in my country (Iran) and good relations between Iran regime and Russia, I guess they are redirecting our requests to Russia to maybe monitor and spy on our traffic by probably better technologies.

How can I tell this is a regular thing (maybe misconfiguration of DNS or something) or an sign of spying?

here is the output of `tracert www.amd.com`:

```
Tracing route to a24.g.akamai.net [213.155.158.25]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms     4 ms     1 ms  SHOHADAROUTER [192.168.81.1]
  2    17 ms    27 ms     *     192.168.2.1
  3    13 ms    15 ms     7 ms  172.16.1.2
  4    92 ms    98 ms   103 ms  172.16.2.1
  5   199 ms    89 ms     *     217.219.236.20
  6   115 ms     *      162 ms  78.38.245.57
  7   561 ms    89 ms   156 ms  195.146.63.253
  8   106 ms   101 ms   110 ms  195.175.5.21
  9     *      188 ms   199 ms  turktelekom-ic-134131-ldn-b5.c.telia.net [213.24
8.104.42]
 10   192 ms   195 ms   192 ms  ldn-b5-link.telia.net [213.248.104.41]
 11   204 ms   214 ms   206 ms  ldn-bb2-link.telia.net [80.91.252.201]
 12     *      227 ms   220 ms  hbg-bb2-link.telia.net [80.239.147.186]
 13   240 ms   329 ms   246 ms  s-bb2-link.telia.net [80.91.251.42]
 14   280 ms   345 ms   284 ms  s-b2-link.telia.net [80.91.246.235]
 15   276 ms   232 ms   264 ms  s-hdn-i4-link.telia.net [80.91.249.209]
 16   167 ms   179 ms     *     213-155-158-25.customer.teliacarrier.com [213.15
5.158.25]
 17   163 ms   169 ms   162 ms  213-155-158-25.customer.teliacarrier.com [213.15
5.158.25]

Trace complete.
```

Comment: this question is off-topic for Server Fault and fits here better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No one is "spying" on your internet connection. If they are, the spying is surely *not* causing this behavior. Rather, this is most likely due to an incorrect entry in the database of whatever [IP Geolocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation_software) system being used by the website of interest.

Comment: The first public IP address in his traceroute (thus most likely on the same subnet as the NAT gateway his traffic appears to be coming from) is 217.219.236.20, which, on the first GeoIP site I tried, comes up as Iran. Do you know of any GeoIP services that list that IP as Russia?